# How to save table in Excel worksheet as CSV in VBA and continue working on the previous file

Tags: excel, vba, csv

I am trying to export tables from different sheets, if there is an alteration made to it, as CSV data.

My code exports all tables from my file. How can I make it export only the current table that I am executing the macro on?

```vb
Public Sub SaveWorksheetsAsCsv()
Dim xWs As Worksheet
Dim xDir As String
Dim folder As FileDialog
Set folder = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

If folder.Show <> -1 Then Exit Sub

xDir = folder.SelectedItems(1)

For Each xWs In Application.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
xWs.SaveAs xDir & "\" & xWs.name, xlCSV
Next

End Sub
```

I figured out a way but now the window opens as a CSV file. How do I close the csv file and reopen the worksheet I was working on?

```vb
Public Sub SaveWorksheetsAsCsvUndercarriageDefinition()
Dim wbk As Workbook
Dim xWs As Worksheet
Dim xDir As String
Dim folder As FileDialog

Set wbk = Workbooks("Vba_Fehlerprüfung.xlsm")
Set xWs = wbk.Worksheets("Undercarriage Definition")
Set folder = 
Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
If folder.Show <> -1 Then Exit Sub
xDir = folder.SelectedItems(1)
'For Each xWs In Application.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
xWs.SaveAs xDir & "\" & xWs.name, xlCSV
'Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Please check out the [ActiveSheet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.activesheet).

Comment: Use the [search function](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=excel+export+csv+from+vba), the topic of "exporting from Excel to CSV using VBA code" has been covered many times.   I usually recommend not to use `xlCSV` and SaveAs, because Excel enforces various settings, such as delimiter and quoting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suggestion would be to use the following sub in order to export a table resp. an listobject

```
Sub exportListobject(lo As ListObject, csvFilename As String)
    
    Dim wbNew As Workbook
    Set wbNew = Workbooks.Add
    
    Dim wsNew As Worksheet

    With wbNew
        Set wsNew = wbNew.Sheets(1)
        lo.Range.Copy
        wsNew.Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll
        .SaveAs Filename:=csvFilename, _
            FileFormat:=xlCSVMSDOS, CreateBackup:=False
        .Close False
    End With

End Sub
```

It will copy the listobject in question into a new workbook, save it as an csv file and close it. The workbook which contains the listobject will not be touched.

If you want to export a single sheet from your workbook you can use a similar sub

```
Sub exportSheet(sh As Worksheet, csvFilename As String)

    Dim wbNew As Workbook
    Set wbNew = Workbooks.Add
    
    Dim wsNew As Worksheet

    With wbNew
        sh.Copy wbNew.Sheets(1)
        Set wsNew = wbNew.Sheets(1)
        .SaveAs Filename:=csvFilename, _
            FileFormat:=xlCSVMSDOS, CreateBackup:=False
        .Close False
    End With

End Sub
```