# How to save Excel file in .csv format?

Tags: excel, vba

The code below creates and saves all the Excel sheets from "Test_Main" into separate new workbooks with file extension .xlsx.

I want it to save the workbook in .csv format.

```vb
Sub Workbook()

Dim a As Integer
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim wb As Workbook

a = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count  'counts all the sheets

For i = 1 To a 'loops for all sheets
    If ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(i).Name <> "Test_Main" Then 'rule out the main sheet

        Set wb = Workbooks.Add
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(i).Copy before:=wb.Worksheets(1) 'new workbook has 1 worksheet by deafult
        wb.SaveAs "H:\IT\Melissa\Essengeld\TEST\" & ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(i).Name

        wb.Close savechages = True

    End If
Next i

ThisWorkbook.Activate
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Activate
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 1).Select

MsgBox ("Task Completed")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft answer  question here -> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.saveas

Comment: ` wb.SaveAs "H:\IT\Melissa\Essengeld\TEST\" & ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(i).Name, FileFormat:=xlCSV ` I tried this code but it won't work. Is this code correct?

Comment: Right way is this -> Call wb.SaveAs("filename.csv", XlFileFormat.xlCSV)

Comment: Shows a syntax failure :(

Answer (score 0):

I took code from to export a sheet from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73189823/6600940)

```
Sub exportSheet(sh As Worksheet, csvFilename As String)

    Dim wbNew As Workbook
    Set wbNew = Workbooks.Add
    
    Dim wsNew As Worksheet

    With wbNew
        sh.Copy wbNew.Sheets(1)
        Set wsNew = wbNew.Sheets(1)
        .SaveAs Filename:=csvFilename, _
            FileFormat:=xlCSVMSDOS, CreateBackup:=False
        .Close False
    End With

End Sub
```

and used it in your code like that

```
Sub exportToCSV()

    Dim a As Integer
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim wb As Workbook

    a = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count  'counts all the sheets

    For i = 1 To a 'loops for all sheets
        If ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(i).Name <> "Test_Main" Then 'rule out the main sheet

'            Set wb = Workbooks.Add
'            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(i).Copy before:=wb.Worksheets(1) 'new workbook has 1 worksheet by deafult
'            wb.SaveAs "H:\IT\Melissa\Essengeld\TEST\" & ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(i).Name
'
'            wb.Close savechages = True
             exportSheet ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(i), "H:\IT\Melissa\Essengeld\TEST\" & ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(i).Name
        End If
    Next i

    ThisWorkbook.Activate
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Activate
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 1).Select

    MsgBox ("Task Completed")
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks alot! Could you alter my code to save only specific worksheets. For example I have 10 worksheets and want only worksheets 2-5 to be saved.

Comment: I think it's best you try something on your own and if you get stuck you post a question here.

Comment: I did :) `For i = 2 To 5`  I just changed the values of the for loop and it works.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:

wb.SaveAs "H:\IT\Melissa\Essengeld\TEST" & ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(i).Name , FileFormat:=xlCSV